# ASP.NET MVC 4 Partial View Post Method on a form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, http-post, partial-views

I have a partial view that is called _GetForfaitDashBoard.cshtml
This is the code

```
@model WebAppComp.Areas.Admin.Models.StatsForfaitDashBoard


<table class ="table table-bordered">
<tr>
<th>Nombre total de Forfaits</th>
<th>Moyenne des forfaits par Agence</th>
<th>Forfait Ayant le prix le plus haut</th>
<th>Forfait Ayant le prix le plus bas</th>
<th>Le forfait le plus visité</th>
<th>Le forfait le mieux noté par les membres</th>
<th>le forfait ayant le plus de réservations</th>
<th>le forfait le plus récent</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>@Model.CountForfaits</td>
<td>@Model.AverageCountForfaitPerAgence</td>
<td>@Html.ActionLink("Ici", "GetById", "Agence", new { numSiretAgence = Model.IdHighestPriceForfait }, null)</td>
<td>@Html.ActionLink("Ici", "GetById", "Agence", new { numSiretAgence = Model.IdLowestPriceForfait }, null)</td>
<td>@Html.ActionLink("Ici", "GetById", "Agence", new { numSiretAgence = Model.IdMostVisitedForfait }, null)</td>
<td>@Html.ActionLink("Ici", "GetById", "Agence", new { numSiretAgence = Model.IdBestRatedForfait }, null)</td>
<td>@Html.ActionLink("Ici", "GetById", "Agence", new { numSiretAgence = Model.IdMostBookedForfait}, null)</td>
<td>@Html.ActionLink("Ici", "GetById", "Agence", new { numSiretAgence = Model.IdMostRecentForfait}, null)</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

It's a table in which I put statistics.
What I want to do is to have these statistics loaded in a web page based on a **Form** , the form will contain a simple dropdownlist in which the user choses the type of statistics that he wants.
Here is the code of the partial View Action :

```
[HttpPost]
        public PartialViewResult _GetForfaitDashBoard (TypeForfait typeForfait)
        {
            .....
        }
```

Now I don't know how to do to put all I said into action. Is putting a form in the base view that posts to the action of the Partial View will be a good approach? Or is there any other solutions to call a partial view based on a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're returning a PartialView my suggestion would be:

Use the [jQuery Change event](http://api.jquery.com/change/) to get the selected value from your dropdownlist and post it to the server.

```
$("#yourdropdownid").change(function(e){}
```

Then post your data (my personal preference is via a [Ajax request](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) but you can also use the [Post function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)) to your `_GetForfaitDashBoard` action and handle the response in your javascript:

```
$("#yourdropdownid").change(function(e){
    var selectedValue = this.val();

    $.ajax({
       url: $("#yourFormId").attr("action"),
       type: "POST",
       data: { typeForfait: selectedValue }, 
       success: function(response){ $('#IdOfTheElementWhereYouWantToInsert').html(response) },
       error: function(){ // handle your error }
    });
}
```

The `response` parameter in the success function is the rendered html of the partialView.

Assuming that you're basing the type of statistics only on the selected value I would suggest to change your parameter type from TypeForfait to string (or an int) in your action.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult _GetForfaitDashBoard (string typeForfait)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reponse, this seems the right approach, but one more question, how can I inject the partial view in the page, I mean what shall I put in // inject you partial view on the page ? Sorry I am new to jquery ..

Comment: No problem, will edit my answer. You can do it with the .html() function of jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: also there is a little problem **url: $("#yourFormId").attr("href")** should be url: **$("#yourFormId").attr("action")** you can edit the answer for someone who has the same question :)

Comment: You can also put in the url in your javascript and remove the form, then you don't need this statement at all. But that's a personal preference.